# How to assign role to a custom registration form?

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

I am working on a custom registration form. How can I assign a role of "participant" to the new user? I tried many methods but did not succeed; the role change is not reflected in the admin user's list.

Comment: Do you mean assign a specific role to a user automatically when they sign up?

Comment: yes, It should be "participant" who can see the post only.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `New User Default Role` in General Settings?

Comment: by coding how will i add in custom registration form?

Comment: You should show what you have tried or researched. That way we can assist you better and we won't loose time trying to explain things you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is, when you are submitting the registration form, define a value for the 'role' and then pass it with `wp_insert_user` [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user).

Like this:

```
$fields_user = get_fields_user(); //get the values from the form and put them in an array.
$fields_user['role'] = 'participant'; //define a value for the key 'role'
$user_id = wp_insert_user($fields_user); //get all the info and register it with the wp_insert_user
```

But that role has to be already created in the admin

Answer (score -1):

go to setting > general > New User Default Role change to participant

Comment: That is not even remotely close to what the OP needs.